# 2009 Chevy Malibu key programming failed

Tags: key, program

I took the steps to program my newly cut key because I lost my original key...After going through the steps I must have done something wrong because now the car is just black and won't do anything. Lights won't come on or nothing...Can you please help me in solving thins problem?

Answer (score 1):

What steps have you tried? Some systems require you to have an original key present in order to program a new one (use the original one to disarm the system, then program the new one), so you might find that without any originals, you have to go back to the dealer to get the new one programmed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you tripped out the anti-theft system. If that is the case you would need a factory scan tool or something equivalent to unlock it. I did it on a 06 Malibu and the anti-theft system freaked out.

It thinks that someone may possibly be tampering with the electrical or computer system, so it just erases all knowledge of keys and locks down. It's a good measure because car hacking is becoming an extremely popular hobby and crime haha.
I would check that out, or take it to the dealer. You might be able to complain enough to get them to help you out with a little information before you have to take it in and pay. It literally only takes 30 minutes for them to hook up a scan tool and reset you locking system.

Also, if you are leasing the car it might have an aftermarket module that can shut down the vehicle if you didn't pay your bills on time. They also have anti-theft systems as well that can screw with things. I've seen them just malfunction for absolutely no reason and have had to tow them to the shop. I hope you get it figured out!